# ember: manipulate the DOM (like hide a long list of items)

Tags: ember.js

I'm new to ember.  I have a demo app working, and I'm moving towards making it look nice.

One issue I'm starting to grapple with is how to manipulate DOM elements.  Coming from a server-side world, it's been pretty easy to just throw some jquery at stuff like this.  Doesn't appear to be as straightforward in ember.  But I'm probably missing something or approaching it wrong.

The immediate problem is: I have a list of 40-some `<li>` elements and I want to create a toggle to show/hide the list after the first 10 items.

I got something to work in my component like this:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

let $ = Ember.$;

export default Ember.Component.extend({ 

    didInsertElement() {
        this._super(...arguments);
        Ember.run.scheduleOnce('afterRender', this, this.afterRenderEvent);
    },

    afterRenderEvent() {
        let listTotal = $("#myList li").length;
        $("#myList li").slice(10, listTotal).hide();        
    }
});
```

The problem is that when actions trigger and the view is re-rendered, afterRenderEvent() doesn't get called again, and the list shows in its entirety.

The above component corresponds to this template:

```
<ul id="myList">
{{#each aggs.categories as |category|}}
    <li><a href="#" {{action (action add "filter_breadcrumb" category.key)}}>{{category.key}} ({{category.doc_count}})</a></li>
{{/each}}
</ul>
```

Is there a way to get around this?  OR, is there a more "ember" way to approach this problem (and DOM manipulation in general)?

Comment: where `myList` div and its `li` rendered ? is it in the same component ?.

Comment: Yes, sorry about that.  Same component.  I edited the OP to include the template code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Introduce `showCount` property in controller and have action to set `showCount` to total list count.

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
    showCount: 10,
    actions: {
        setShowCount(count) {
            //you can set total count
            this.set('showCount', count);
        }
    }
});
```

Install [ember truth helpers addon](https://github.com/jmurphyau/ember-truth-helpers) or write computed property to check.

```
<ul id="myList">
{{#each aggs.categories as |category index|}}
    <li style="{{if (gt index showCount) 'display:none'}}"><a href="#" {{action (action add "filter_breadcrumb" category.key)}}>{{category.key}} ({{category.doc_count}})</a></li>
{{/each}}
</ul>
```

If you don't want to display then you can just iterate just `showCount` `aggs.categories` alone by writing computed property or using [ember-composable-helpers junk](https://github.com/DockYard/ember-composable-helpers#chunk) method

```
<ul id="myList">
    {{#each (chunk showCount aggs.categories) as |category index|}}
        <li><a href="#" {{action (action add "filter_breadcrumb" category.key)}}>{{category.key}} ({{category.doc_count}})</a></li>
    {{/each}}
    </ul>
```

Comment: agh!  so simple.  I like the index method.  That way I can add a "show more" link that calls a jquery effect .show().  Thanks so much man!

Comment: well, I *thought* I had it.  But I am running into my original issue - when the model refreshes, my jquery no longer works.  https://discuss.emberjs.com/t/what-are-the-rules-for-using-jquery-to-manipulate-the-dom/12433